# How can I have a secure MongoDB - Mongoose setup?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, mongoose

I am developing a Node.js app that will use MongoDB and I am trying to make it as secure as possible.

### Authentication to the database

First, I wanted to restrict the access to the database, so I added an authentication. So now, in the terminal, I have to login like so :

`~$ mongo -u <myusername> -p --authenticationDatabase admin`

But then, in my javascript I had to add the password in plain text in the following line :

```
// Connect to the database 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/<myDB>?authSource=admin', {user: <myusername>, pass: <mypassword>, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
```

This disturbs me. It brings me to my first question : **How can I have a restricted access to my database without having plain text passwords in the code ?**

---

### Between Mongoose and MongoDB

I discovered that Mongoose communicates with MongoDB via TCP/IP. I ran a wireshark to see if I could detect data and in fact I could :
[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUfGL.png)

The back-end and the MongoDB may likely be on 2 different machines. This brings me to my last question : I have seen on multiple posts here that, sometimes, a SSH connection was made, but **is it the best way to secure the communication ?**

Comment: Environment variables?

Comment: Besides using enviroment variables if you want to protect data at the TCP level, you could have a look at enabling SSL on the mongodb [SSL/TLS Mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB doesn’t enable access control by default. Running a MongoDB instance without access control means that anyone that can connect to the database can run commands and potentially see all data in the database.

After enabling access control to force all users to authenticate when connecting to the database, the next step is to configure role-based access control (RBAC).

Here's the checklist for MongoDB Security: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/

It's normal to supplied username and password even in other RDBMS
Please check the authentication part of MongoDB here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/

Also how you enable the authentication:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

To answer you 2nd question regarding communications, you can check the link I sent https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/ and goto Encrypt Communication, It uses TLS/SSL to encrypt communication between mongod and mongos.

Regards,